# nodejs turn string into array to upload to google sheets

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, discord.js

**Main Goals**

1. Retrieve string from google sheets tab.
2. Edit string to remove "s and ,s.
3. re-format the string for upload into google sheets.

I have accomplished the first 2 tasks of my goal. Although I will explain in full the situation.

I am querying google sheets to return a row which contains a specified string so it can be added to a new sheet. currently I have been able to retrieve the row fine. the data comes back looking like this.

> "12/24/2020, 3:40:33 PM","SanguineDepths+5","The Key Is
> Timed","1000","Aegwynn","@name @name @name @[Manager]
> name-name","name#0000 name#0000 name#0000
> name#0000","Advertiser-Realm","testing-testing","Ticket","33p2bdlfto9g45","Customer-Realm","Horde",""

I have then used the following code to remove all of the "s and ,s.

```js
const result = `"12/24/2020, 3:40:33 PM","SanguineDepths+5","The Key Is Timed","1000","Aegwynn","@name @name @name @[Manager] name-name ","name#0000 name#0000 name#0000 name#0000","Advertiser-Realm","testing-testing","Ticket","33p2bdlfto9g45","Customer-Realm","Horde",""`

var result1 = result.replace (/,/g, " ");
var result2 = result1.replace (/"/g, "");
```

Now my string is looking like this.

> 12/24/2020  3:40:33 PM SanguineDepths+5 Timed 1000 Aegwynn @name @name
> @name  @[Manager] name-name name#0000 name#0000 name#0000
> name#0000 Advertiser-Realm testing-testing Ticket 33p2bdlfto9g45
> Customer-Realm Horde

When uploading the above string which removes the characters I do not require, google sheets actually inputs all of the data in one cell instead of multiple, is there a way I can fix this? I did try to use arguments although I would like the 4 discord name#0000 in one cell and the 4 discord @name also in their own cell, like this.

[Desired format for data to be entered in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcGOm.png)

So my main goal is to format the result in such a way I can write them to google sheets in their own cells.

Edit #1

I have used the .split(',') function but google API returns the following error:

"The API returned an error: Error: Invalid values[1][0]: list_value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping for an easier solution, but I ended up using this method with multiple arguments for the string I got back from the sheet.

```js
var result1 = result.replace (/,/g, " ");
                    var result2 = result1.replace (/"/g, "");

                    const argsRUN = result2.split(' ');
                    const command = argsRUN.shift().toLowerCase();

                    var date1 = (argsRUN[0]);
                    var time1 = (argsRUN[1]);
                    var ampm = (argsRUN[2]);
                    var dungeonkey = (argsRUN[3]);
                    var timedornot = (argsRUN[4]);
                    var costofboost = (argsRUN[5]);
                    var paymentrealm1 = (argsRUN[6]);
                    var boost1ID = (argsRUN[7]);
                    var boost2ID = (argsRUN[8]);
                    var boost3ID = (argsRUN[9]);
                    var boost4ID = (argsRUN[10]);
                    var boost1tag = (argsRUN[11]);
                    var boost2tag = (argsRUN[12]);
                    var boost3tag = (argsRUN[13]);
                    var boost4tag = (argsRUN[14]);
                    var advertiserrealm = (argsRUN[15]);
                    var commentup = (argsRUN[16]);
                    var ticketornot = (argsRUN[17]);
                    var uniquerunid = (argsRUN[18]);
                    var customerrealm = (argsRUN[19]);
                    var customerfaction = (argsRUN[20]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to target the comma's in between to split the data at that point to an array and then take care of removing charcters.
Try:

```js
result.split(',')
```

That should give you an Array.
And you could resuse your code to take out the characters you don't need with an array helper: something like:

```js
result.split(',').map((part) => {
 return part.replace (/"/g, "")
})
```

Comment: I did actually try this, I forgot to add it to my initial question. 

When using the .split() function I end up getting errors from google's API;

"The API returned an error: Error: Invalid values[1][0]: list_value"

Comment: The first code returned an API error, the second returned the string with the "s and ,s still in the string. Rather strange.